# Beginner Project: Element Symbol Finder

Tags: python

I want to create a program with asks for the element and then outputs the symbol. Should I use a dictionary or another file. Is this program already done and if so can anyone please show me.
All replies appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the elements in the periodic table.
In that case you can load them into a table using an online "table". You would have to be familiar with **Pandas** and **Dictionaries** to understand the code below.

```
import pandas as pd

# https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2793/where-can-i-find-a-downloadable-spreadsheet-of-element-properties
df = pd.read_csv("http://pastebin.com/raw/CKwm136x", skipinitialspace=True)
df.index = df["Name"]

# Export to a dictionary
dict_ = df.to_dict("index")

# Get the Symbol of Curium
print(dict_["Curium"]["Symbol"])
print("Melting point: {} degrees".format(dict_["Curium"]["Melting_Point"]))
```

Comment: How do I install pandas

Comment: pip install pandas

Comment: I get an error saying:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 2, in <module>
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>

Comment: I would really recommend you to install Anacondas (which include many important scientific libraries including pandas) Website: https://www.continuum.io/downloads